# how to add flip screen animation on button click programmatically

Tags: iphone

I want to flip the view on button click programmatically.

Comment: Please post some code so we can see an example of what you are doing- have you already tried to flip a view, or are you starting from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[[self view] addSubview:secondaryView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Please write the above code in the button action.

In the code second view refers, the view which you want to show after flip.

Comment: hello satya the code is working fine.but on my screen there are two buttons.so when on flip its looking both buttons are coming from upper left corner..so it looks like my controls are moving from corner to its co-ordinate.please help me...i have [[object.windo] addSubview:secondaryView]insted of this line[[self view] addSubview:secondaryView] in your code..hope this will help you to solve my query

Comment: @neel: Here the problem is not by using the statement. The problem is by setting the position of buttons. Actually By default, every view position is taken as (0,0). Then it will change to the position given by us. So what you have to do is first of all set the frame of two buttons in the viewDidLoad method. By doing that your problem may solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use + (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion with UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight or  UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft for the options parameter.